# Node.js Error: Request aborted in File upload formidable

Tags: node.js, gridfs

I am using formidable module https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable to upload images. I created a separate new project & file upload works perfectly.

But when i integrate it in my existing project. I get following error :-

```
Error: Request aborted
at IncomingMessage.onReqAborted (D:\ProjectName\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\node_modules\multiparty\index.js:131:17)
at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
at abortIncoming (http.js:1911:11)
at Socket.serverSocketCloseListener (http.js:1923:5)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
at TCP.close (net.js:466:12)
```

Any idea How to Solve this?

I tried ON event :-

```
form.on('progress', function (bytesReceived, bytesExpected) {
        console.log('PROGRESS');
        console.log(bytesReceived);
        console.log(bytesExpected);
    });
```

It gives me result for above code as :-

```
PROGRESS
0
488
```

It doesn't go ahead of this.

Answer (score 0):

try to delete this in your app.js:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

Comment: Can you explain why deleting this would help? i thought body parser is needed to get the req of a post request?

Answer (score 0):

It might be little late for OP, but for others: just set/increase the nodejs timeout like so:

```
server.timeout = 1000 * 60 * 10; // 10 mins
```

formidable uses this setting after which it throws the "abort" and "error" event. you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23926952/3218429) for details

Comment: I had the problem with fluent-ffmpeg processing taking too long (more then default setting of 2 minutes) which resulted in _Request aborted_)

Answer (score 0):

For later versions of express (i.e. `express@^4.x`) where `body-parser` is deprecated, delete, remove or comment out any `app.use(express.json())` in your entry `.js` or `.ts` file.