# How to modify the nodejs request default timeout time?

Tags: node.js, express, request, timeout

I'm using a Node/express server.  The default timeout of express is 120,000 ms, but it is not enough for me.  When my response reaches 120,000 ms, the console will log `POST /additem 200 120006ms` and the page shows an error, so I want to set the timeout to a larger value.  How would I do that?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using `express`, given the logs you have in your question.  The key is to set the `timeout` property on server (the following sets the timeout to one second, use whatever value you want):

```
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
server.timeout = 1000;
```

If you're not using express and are only working with vanilla node, the principle is the same.  The following will not return data:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
  }, 200);
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');

server.timeout = 20;
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Comment: Do you know how often the timeout function runs? Like every second? Every 500 ms?

Comment: Where is this documented?

Answer (score 43):

Try this:

```
var options = {
    url:  'http://url',
    timeout: 120000
}

request(options, function(err, resp, body) {});
```

Refer to [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request)'s documentation for other options.

Comment: I have tried this,but it doesn't work.when the response reaches 120000 ms, the console still display `POST /additem 200 120006ms` and the page shows error.

Comment: Could it be server side time-out setting?

Comment: We should really differentiate between _incoming_ http request and _outgoing_ http request.

Comment: If you are using your node app as a proxy, you may want to use both `require('request')` and `require('express')`. In such a case, when you make a data via the `request` module, it will only execute your callback once the request is complete. By specifying the `timeout` as @Lee is suggesting, you are 'failing' the request and calling the callback before data is returned. For me, this is often better than failing via express, as @SomeKittens suggests, because I often require cleanup from my request before exiting the process. I would suggest using 2000 (2 sec) rather than 120000 (2 mins)

Comment: timeout it's a valid param  https://github.com/request/request#user-content-requestoptions-callback

Comment: Note that if the underlying TCP connection cannot be established, the OS-wide TCP connection timeout will overrule the timeout option (the default in Linux can be anywhere from 20-120 seconds). https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#requestoptions-callback

Answer (score 24):

[Linking to express issue #3330](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3330)

You may set the timeout either globally for entire server:

```
var server = app.listen();
server.setTimeout(500000);
```

or just for specific route:

```
app.post('/xxx', function (req, res) {
   req.setTimeout(500000);
});
```

Comment: was just going to add this answer myself. was looking for this specifically but didn't see your answer.

Comment: Also note that the *response* has another timeout which you might want to set, too. Consider slowaris attack before blindly setting it to very high number, though.

Comment: Node.js official documentation link for second approach [here](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/all.html#http_request_settimeout_timeout_callback)

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen thanks for pointing that out. I initially set a higher number to emphasize visibility.

Answer (score 16):

For specific request one can set timeOut to 0 which is no timeout till we get reply from DB or other server

```
request.setTimeout(0)
```

Comment: My tests show this to work but I cannot find any documentation for this?

Comment: From [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#socketsettimeouttimeout-callback): If `timeout` is 0, then the existing idle timeout is disabled.

Answer (score 5):

For those having configuration in `bin/www`, just add the timeout parameter after http server creation.

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
/**
* Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces
*/
server.listen(port);
server.timeout=yourValueInMillisecond
```

Comment: Hi Rohith. This works perfectly fine in local machine but doesn't work when deployed. Any idea why?

Comment: How are you running it in deployment? Is it using PM2, forever?. Is bin/www used for HTTP server configuration when deployed or from any other source?.

Comment: If behavior changes when running on actual server, you may be having flakey connection (TCP/IP connection drops randomly) or you have some kind of (more or less transparent) reverse proxy in between causing the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest NodeJS you can experiment with this monkey patch:

```
const http = require("http");
const originalOnSocket = http.ClientRequest.prototype.onSocket;
require("http").ClientRequest.prototype.onSocket = function(socket) {
    const that = this;
    socket.setTimeout(this.timeout ? this.timeout : 3000);
    socket.on('timeout', function() {
        that.abort();
    });
    originalOnSocket.call(this, socket);
};
```