# Node.js server not waiting for more than approx. 15 sec

Tags: node.js, express, timeout

I am running a GET method of router on NodeJS with Express.js.

I am fetching data from MSSQL but my MSSQL server taking a time and my NodeJS server is not waiting for it more than approximately 15 seconds.

What should i do??

Comment: 15 seconds is very long for execute a query. Try to reduce that time by adding oen or more indexes. See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925284/how-to-modify-the-nodejs-request-default-timeout-time) SO question.

Comment: Probably increase [`requestTimeout`](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql#general-same-for-all-drivers).

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925284/how-to-modify-the-nodejs-request-default-timeout-time

Answer (score 7):

You do everything right. But, default timeout in tedious is 15 seconds.
Use **requestTimeout** for

```
let config = {
    user: global.config.database.username,
    password: process.env.database_pwd || process.env.DATABASE_PWD,
    server: global.config.database.host,
    port: 1433,
    database: global.config.database.database,
    requestTimeout: 180000
};

module.exports.connect = async () => {
    pool = await sql.connect(config);
}
```