# routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:535:

Tags: node.js, ssl

I am new to node.js, I am trying to make a request in node js using `https.request()`
it runs fine most of the time but some times I get

```
"Error: 140735698641856:error:1408F119:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:535:"
```

this happens mostly when the response data is large.
I have tried setting timeout also, based on this question

[How to modify the nodejs request default timeout time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925284/how-to-modify-the-nodejs-request-default-timeout-time)

but it also doesn't helped.
Does I need to apply timeout to each request in https options:-

```
var options = new https_options();
    var client_id = clientid;
    var client_secret = clientsecret;
    options.rejectUnauthorized = false;                                         
    options.host = host;
    options.port = port;
    options.path = url_mapping.base_url;
    options.headers = headers;
    options.agent = keepAliveAgent;
    options.method = 'POST';
```

I am using above https options. 
I am using express and swagger.