# Node JS Connection LifeTime

Tags: node.js, oracle, connection

When I am running React App through NodeJS - My Node Js is not returning data after few minutes as my query is taking longer time.
Can anyone please help me out to know how to increase Node Js Connection Timeout to database.

Details:
Database : Oracle
Connection - Express

Comment: Can you update your question with more detail: are you getting a hang or an error?  What error?  What DB module are you using - node-oracledb?

Comment: this came up first in google search 'nodejs increase timeout'- perhaps it might help? 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925284/how-to-modify-the-nodejs-request-default-timeout-time