# Can not run bubble wrap

Tags: node.js, npm, bubblewrap

I'm trying to run BubbleWrap, this is the error that I run into

```
bubblewrap build
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bubblewrap/cli/node_modules/uuid/dist/esm-browser/index.js:1
export { default as v1 } from './v1.js';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bubblewrap/cli/node_modules/googleapis-common/build/src/apirequest.js:20:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
```

I'm using nodejs version 14.18.0 and npm version 6.14.15

I didn't make any changes to the code and I didn't know much about nodejs to know what's going on

Can someone help, please?

thanks

Comment: - Try to change server timeout to more than a minute as describben here => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925284/how-to-modify-the-nodejs-request-default-timeout-time
You should also show the code responsible for uploading a file. Show a minified example showing the problem please.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I download bubblewrap with nodejs v 8
I reinstall with nodejs 14 and it works now

thanks